# jQuery getAttribute in IE8 replacement

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-8, custom-data-attribute

I am trying to get the following code to work in IE8:

**jQuery:**

```
$(".scroll, .tobottom, .video-cta").on("click",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = "#" + $(this).getAttribute("data-target") + " h1";
    $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $(target).position().top
    }, {duration: 2000, easing: "easeInOutQuint"});
});
```

Basically, the HTML that would be associated with something like this would be:

**HTML:**

```
<a class="scroll" href="#" data-target="videocontent">Some content</a>
```

Because IE8 doesn't support getAttribute, I am trying to find a way to get the data-target in all browsers. Any advice?

Comment: `$(this).attr("data-target");`

Comment: The [`getAttribute` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536429(v=vs.85).aspx) *is* supported in IE 8. You're trying to call it off of a jQuery collection, where it is *not* present.

Answer (score 2):

`getAttribute` isn't a jQuery method - `attr()` is:

```
var target = "#" + $(this).attr("data-target") + " h1";
```

That should work.

Alternately, use the `.data()` method:

```
var target = "#" + $(this).data("target") + " h1";
```

All jQuery methods are designed to work even in old IE, at least in jQuery 1.x.

Comment: I tried both of the methods you suggested, and it isn't working. Seems like no matter which scroll button I click, it always scrolls me back to the same place, even though, through data-target, it should take me to that target. Both methods you mentioned work in everything but IE8.

Comment: Maybe you're actually having trouble with the scrolling.